# Getting error "Version could not be created from build" while deploying WPF app to Hockeyapp via VSTS

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, hockeyapp

Everything works fine when I deploy using Visual Studio "Distribute to HockeyApp" option in VS project. But when I do the same using VSTS

> HTTP status code: 422. Responce: {"status":"error","message":"Version
>   could not be created from build."}

Can anyone please help me?

Adding build config.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the detail build and release logs on the OneDrive? (Set/add system.debug variable to true, then queue build/start release)

Comment: Tried setting debug to false and not getting enough. Added build config to the question.

Comment: Can you share the logs here or on the OneDrive? (Set debug to true) On the other hand, can you publish the built result (zip) to hockeyapp manually?

Comment: manually getting same error.

Comment: I was getting this error because I didn't have the HockeySDK properly installed on my cordova app SMH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message already indicated the root cause: It cannot find the build version.

If you click on the icon after "Binary File Path", you'll find that it is used to deploy .apk, .ipa and .appx files. These kinds of files include a version in the packages. I suspect that it is a limitation with the task when deploy zip files since zip files does not include the version information. And when you deploy from Visual Studio, it requires you to enter the version manually.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the reply. I got to solve the problem using HockeyApp public API. As it is a zip file so we get it upload into Hockey, I created version and updated same version. https://gist.github.com/Geertvdc/cad0e2191243fb76c55f. Now I am using powershell to create and update version. This link really helped.