# VSTS : Unable to upload to HockeyApp

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, hockeyapp

As I'm trying to upload an iPad application (XCode project) to HockeyApp with VSTS's build pipeline, it fails and returns following error message.

[image]

```
2018-07-30T10:37:57.0420460Z ##[error]Error: Failed to upload the package. HTTP status code: 422. Responce: {"status":"error","message":"Version could not be created from build. Please make sure that your .ipa file has the correct format."}
```

All other tasks in the pipeline such as applying certificate / provision profile / XCode build succeeds but it fails in the last Hockeyapp task.

Any idea what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is : It cannot find the build version.

There is a limitation with the task when deploy `zip` files since zip files does not include the version information.

> If you click on the icon after "Binary File Path", you'll find that it
>   is used to deploy .apk, .ipa and .appx files. These kinds of files
>   include a version in the packages. I suspect that it is a limitation
>   with the task when deploy zip files since zip files does not include
>   the version information. And when you deploy from Visual Studio, it
>   requires you to enter the version manually.

As a workaround, you can use HockeyApp public API, upload the zip file into Hockey, write a PowerShell script to create and update version (Reference this script: [UploadUWPToHockeyapp.ps1](https://gist.github.com/Geertvdc/cad0e2191243fb76c55f) ).

Reference the similar issue here : [Getting error "Version could not be created from build" while deploying WPF app to Hockeyapp via VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798394/getting-error-version-could-not-be-created-from-build-while-deploying-wpf-app)

Comment: @ReshanKumarasingam Have you resolved the issue? any update?